# Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {links}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: reactjs, api, object, error-handling, javascript-objects

Im trying to figure out how to handle different API responses and map over them. So i can present them in my application.

Handeling the getArrayofObjects function is no problem at all. However, the Nasa API contains object structure with nested objects within.

```
{
element_count: 25,
links: {
next: https:link1.com,
prev: https:linkprev.com,
self: https:linkself.com }
},
near_earth_objects: {
2015-09-08: [{absolute_magnitude_h: 19.3, 
close_approach_data: [{close_approachdate: 2015:01:12}]}, 
estimated-diameter: {}, id: 132342323, links: {}]
```

i want to map over this object however react gives me the error mentioned in the title. How can i map over this data and allow it to be presented orderly in the application?

I have the following component:

```
    import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
    const axios = require('axios')
    import { useState } from 'react'
    
    export default function Home() {
        const [nasa, setNasa] = useState([])
        const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])
    
        const returnNestedObjects = () => {
            axios
                .get(
                    'https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2015-09-07&end_date=2015-09-08&api_key=hqIAqlEjXdGOE4K0H44Oj0Bq20tID1ytS3IdYuT4'
                ) // goed kijken naar de API of het de juiste data heeft als format
                .then((response) => {
                    setNasa(response.data)
                    console.log('Objects of nested NASA objects', response.data) // returs object with nested objects // TODO uitvogelen hoe je deze mapped
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    setIsError(true)
                    console.log(error)
                })
        }
    
        const results = Object.keys(nasa).map((key) => {
            console.log(key) // ️ name, element_count, near_earth_objects, links console logt the key
            console.log(nasa[key]) // ️ {next: somelink.com/} 25, {2015-09-08} console logt the value
    
            return { [key]: nasa[key] } // returns key + value
        })
    
        console.log('results', results)
        const stringifyObjects = JSON.stringify(results)
    
        const getArrayofObjects = () => {
            axios
                .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts') // returns Array
                .then((response) => {
                    setPosts(response.data)
                    console.log('Array Of objects', response.data) // returs Array with nested objects => .map to map over them
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    setIsError(true)
                    console.log(error)
                })
        }
    
        return (
            <div className={styles.container}>
                <main className={styles.main}>
                    <h1 className={styles.title}>
                        Welcome to{' '}
                        <span className={styles.headerTitle}>
                            <h2>Testing API API</h2>
                        </span>
                    </h1>
                    <div className={styles.buttoncontainer}>
                        <button onClick={returnNestedObjects}>Nested Objects</button>
                        <button onClick={getArrayofObjects}>Array of Objects</button>
                    </div>
                    <ul>
                        {posts.map((item) => (
                            <li>{item.title}</li>
                        ))}
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        {results ? (
                            <ul>
                                <li>NASA API RESULTS: {results}</li>
                            </ul>
                        ) : (
                            <p>Loading...</p>
                        )}
                    </ul>
                </main>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`results` is Object , no reactElement